# Page not 'active' after mobile.changePage redirect in phonegap JQM app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a strange behaviour in my phonegap application which I cannot seem to find a solution for.

My app has a login form which on successful login, redirects to an update account page.

LOGIN.HTML

```
setTimeout(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage('update-account.html', { reloadPage: true, transition: "slide"} );
}, 2000);
```

Within the update account form

UPDATE-ACCOUNT.HTML

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                                      $('#updateAcc').tap(function(){

                                        var formData = $("#callUpdateForm").serialize();

                                        $.ajax({
                                               type: "POST",
                                               url: "/process/update-account.php",
                                               cache: false,
                                               dataType: 'json', // JSON response
                                               data: formData,
                                               success: function(res) {
                                               if (res.success) {
                                                 $("#notify .success").show(); //show success message
                                                 $("#notify .success").delay(2000).hide("slow");//fades it out
                                                 setTimeout(function() {
                                                    $.mobile.changePage('account.html', { reloadPage: true, transition: "fade"} ); //redirects to profile
                                                 }, 2000);
                                               } else {
                                               // show error message
                                                 $("#notify .error").show();  //show error message
                                                 $("#notify .error").delay(2000).hide("slow"); //fades it out
                                               }
                                               },
                                               error: function() {
                                               alert('not working');
                                               }
                                               });

                                        return false;

                                        });

                                      });

                    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

             function getAccount() {
                     $.getJSON("/json/account.json.php", {id : localStorage.getItem("id")}, function(data){
                     $.each(data, function(key, val){ 
                     // for populatingform
                          $('#usernameField').attr('value', val.username);
                           $('#passwordField').attr('value', val.password);
                         });
                     });

 $(document).ready(function() {
          //form processing goes here and works ok
             getAccount(); 
      });

      </script>

<form id="callAccForm" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="text" name="username" id="usernameField" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" name="newpassword" value="" placeholder="New Password"/>
<a href"#" button id="updateAcc"  data-role="button">Save</a>
</form>
```

The key problem is that after redirect from the login page, whilst the data populates correctly, the update button does not work, in addition to and any other buttons with onclick events. They do however work if I click directly to update-account.html.

Is this something to do with how I am loading the page after redirect? Am I failing to load the content correctly somehow?  It's like it requires a page reload to function correctly.

Comment: at what file have you given the onclik events and how have you loaded them?

Comment: Within the same page I have the function which the button calls on the click event.  I've re-edited my code above

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [repo](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/web-skeletons) which will provide you with a webskeleton for your app jqm+backbone, all issues in animation and issues like yours were solved there. also it is the best skeleton for jqm to make your app light weighted on phonegap